# Oracle partitions and sub-partitions

Tags: oracle, database-partitioning, subpartition

Currently, we use a query similar to the following to add partitions:

```
ALTER TABLE ${" + DDL_VARIABLE_KEY_SCHEMA_NAME + "}.${" +
  DDL_VARIABLE_KEY_TABLE_NAME + "} ADD PARTITION ${" +
  DDL_VARIABLE_KEY_PARTITION_NAME + "} VALUES LESS THAN(${" +
  DDL_VARIABLE_KEY_CUTOFF_DATE + "})"
```

How should I go about creating the query to create the sub-partitions?

Will something like the below suffice? 
or does it need any changes?

```
alter table xxxxx.xxxxx
modify PARTITION BY RANGE (CREATEDATE)
SUBPARTITION BY LIST (PURGEID)
subpartition template(
SUBPARTITION SP1 values (0),
SUBPARTITION SP2 values (1),
SUBPARTITION SP3 values (2),
SUBPARTITION SP4 values (3))
(
PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-JAN-2018', 'DD-MON-YYYY')),
PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-MAY-2018', 'DD-MON-YYYY')),
PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-SEP-2018', 'DD-MON-YYYY')),
PARTITION p5 VALUES LESS THAN (maxvalue)) online;
```

Comment: What is the partition key and what kind of (sub) partition do you use? E.i. RANGE, LIST, INTERVAL, ...

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit        - partition key is createdate, range (createdate) and its Range-List (sub-partitioning)